# A metric space of non-empty closed subsets in a metric space that is bounded and compact is compact.

Tags: general-topology

My title is stated as an exercise.*  A hint for proof is offered.  The proof proceeds to show that a sequence $\{E_n\}$ drawn from the family of closed subsets contains a convergent subsequence.  At the start, for each counting number, $k$, the compact metric space is covered by a finite number of open balls, $B(x_i,1/k),\,\,\,i\,\epsilon\,\{1,N_k\}$.  The hint describes an array of the subsets, as follows: The first horizontal line is the drawn sequence and each line that follows is a subsequence of the preceding.  Further, in each subsequential line the ball, $B(x_i,i/k)$, must either meet every element of the subsequential line, $E_{k,j}$, or meet none of them.
Each ball, for each $x_i$ and each $k$ does either meet a countable number of elements, $\{E_{k-1,j}\}$, of a subsequential line or miss them, so that the next subsequential line, $\{E_{k,j}\}$, is a possibility,  however this is not a constructive definition.   It is not constructive for the following reason:   In attempting to construct the first subsequence from the drawn sequence $\{E_n\}$, one has no way of knowing whether there are a countable number of elements that meet with the ball or a countable number of misses.   Thus, one does not know which  to choose to form the next line.

### What has been demonstrated is that such an array is possible, but no method of constructing it has been offered to my mind.   If I am correct, then I would not go so far as to say the demonstration is faulty.   I would only say that I would like to see an entirely different proof.  Anyone?

- "Introduction to Topology", by Gamelin and Greene, ex 8, p.25

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you ask; do you want a 'constructive' proof?

Comment: The authors describe the forming of the subsequences as constructive.  Thus, I would like it to be constructive.   Otherwise, I should say that what is shown is the existence of such a collection of subsequences.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if there are a countable number of misses. It only matters whether there are finite (bad) or infinite (good) members of the sequence remaining at the end of each step.

Comment: My point is that one cannot really construct the next subsequence without knowing whether to choose the hits or the misses from the preceeding subsequence.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with this.

Comment: Try to form the subsequence $E_{k,j}$ by inspecting the subsequence $E_{k-1,j}$.   How do you know which elements to choose, the hits with the ball or the misses?  You have no way of knowing which are a countable number.

Comment: The truth is I don't entirely understand your question, it is not very clearly written. That said, this is a fairly standard problem in analysis. **If** I understand it right, you choose the 'hits', and since each subsequence is infinite, at least one ball must hit infinite members of the subsequence (because there are finite balls!).

Comment: I am not qualified to chat.

Comment: One may not choose the ball to meet or not to meet.  The choice of the ball comes later in the hint, when it must contain an arbitrary point $x$ of the original compact set.   I thank the moderator and will not comment further.

Comment: The second sentence of my text states that the $E_n$ are elements of a sequence of closed sets drawn from the non-empty, closed family of subsets of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the process if very confusing so I will try to present another proof/description here. It is surely a longer proof than it needs be, but I hope it is 'constructive' enough.

Let $F=B_0$ be the family of closed sets, $X \supset F$ be the bounded and compact metric space, and $\{E_n\}\subset F$ be the sequence . We will inductively construct a convergent subsequence $\{E_{n_k}\}$ as follows.

First, consider the open cover of $X$ given by $\bigcup_{x \in X}B(x,1)$. Since $X$ is compact, there must be a finite subcover of $X$ by balls of radius $1$; of course, this means $B_0$ is covered by a finite number of balls of radius $1$, say $F\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{m_1}B(x^1_i,1)$.

At least one of those balls must contain an infinite number of elements of the sequence $E$, say $B(x^1_{j_1},1)$. Set $B_1=\overline{B(x^1_j,1)}\cap B_0$ and choose any of those elements to be $E_{n_1}$, the first element of our subsequence.

Now, consider the open cover of $X$ given by $\bigcup_{x \in X}B(x,1/2)$. Like before, this implies that $B_1\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{m_2}B(x^2_i,1/2)$. Because $B_1$ contains an infinite number of elements of $E$ and the cover is finite, at least one of those balls must contain an infinite number of elements $E$, say $B(x^2_{j_2},1/2)$. Set $B_2=\overline{B(x^2_{j_2},1/2)}\cap B_1$ and choose any of those elements **with an index greater than $n_1$** to be $E_{n_2}$, the second element of our subsequence. Notice such an element always exist (because $E\cap B_1$ is infinite).

Proceed inductiely in this manner, considering at the $k$-th step an open cover of $X$ by balls of radius $1/k$. The subsequence obtained in this way satisfies $d(E_{n_k},E_{n_{k+l}})\leq 2/k$ for all integers $l\geq 0$, because $E_{n_k},E_{n_{k+l}}\in B_k$ and $B_k$ is contained in a ball of radius $1/k$.

It follows that $\{E_{n_k}\}$ is Cauchy, and hence convergent. Moreover, since $F$ is closed and $\{E_{n_k}\}\subset\{E_n\}\subset F$, the limit is in $F$. This concludes the proof.

Comment: The balls cover $F$, true, because they cover $X$,  That does not mean that there must be one of the finite number of  balls that covers an infinite number of the elements of the sequence $E$.   Each of the finite number of balls could cover a fraction of each element of $E$.  The balls cover $X$.   It is $X$ that by hypothesis is compact.   We do not know that F is compact.

Comment: The metric space of the closed subsets has its own metric $\rho$, different from the metric of the given bounded, compact space $X$.

Comment: I don't see how this changes anything. The finite cover of $X$ also covers $F$. If each (of the finite number) of the balls that cover $F$ had a finite (or empty) intersection with $E$, then $E$ itself would be finite (otherwise, the sequence would have to assume one value an infinite number of times, but this case is trivial anyway).

Comment: Whichever balls cover $E$, not one of them has to do more than meet an $E_n$ that belongs to $E$.   None has to contain an entire $E_n$.   Do we agree?   If you can find a copy of Gamelin and Greene, and have the time to read the exercise, you will overcome the admitted deficiency in my title.

Comment: If the sequence $E_n$ assumes infinitely many distinct values, then at least one of the balls must cover infinitely many of those values.

Comment: The $E_n$ are not values.  They are closed sets.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You should really state your question clearly.

Comment: Yes, you are right!  My apologies.  I regret your spent time.

Comment: It's okay, no worries.